# Did Saddam Hussein have a secret torture chamber in New York City?

Tags: united-states, history, criminology, violence, iraq

The NY Post [reported](http://nypost.com/2016/10/12/inside-saddam-husseins-secret-nyc-torture-chamber/) this week that Saddam Hussein had a secret torture chamber in New York City between 1979 and 2003.

The sources the paper cites are two "anonymous officials". The paper does not note whom these anonymous officials allegedly told this to. However, the NY Post has published quite a detailed (and horrifying) account of it.

Are there any other sources corroborating or contradicting this account, or is the NY Post the only source?

I will list some details from the article. I'm not asking for all of these details to be assessed, I'm merely including them. The main claim to be assessed is that Saddam Hussein had a torture chamber in NYC in which people were tortured and/or murdered.

- Chamber was at the Iraq Mission in NYC where it existed between 1979 and 2003.
- Prisoners were detained, tortured and sometimes killed there, and all of this was used to threaten their relatives in Iraq.
- Prisoners were beaten to pulps and had their nails pulled out.
- Corpses of victims were shipped to Iraq in "diplomatic boxes."

Comment: The NYPost is a tabloid which is well known for its sensationalism so it seems unlikely.

Comment: @ventsyv There are a couple other papers that have also picked up on this story, and while I don't have any good sources to back this up, I would consider this probably true.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Where did those other papers get the information from? Did they just cite the NY Post? If not good sources, what leads you to consider this probably true? I personally have no idea whether this is true or not.